# R package vegan stepacross function error

Tags: r, vegan, distance-matrix

I am trying to use the `stepacross` function in the `vegan` package of R.

When I do, it throws an error and fails to run the code

> Error in stepacross(distance.dat, path = "extended") :
> object 'C_stepacross' not found

**Anybody know the cause of this or what to do to fix it?**

I'm using R (64-bit) 4.0.2 and vegan 2.5-6  (old version use is intentional).

It worked a few weeks ago, and I have made no changes since.

The `C_stepacross` object in question shows up in the `stepacross()` function code:

```
getAnywhere(stepacross)

function (dis, path = "shortest", toolong = 1, trace = TRUE, 
    ...) 
{
    path <- match.arg(path, c("shortest", "extended"))
    if (!inherits(dis, "dist")) 
        dis <- as.dist(dis)
    oldatt <- attributes(dis)
    n <- attr(dis, "Size")
    if (path == "shortest") 
        dis <- .C(dykstrapath, dist = as.double(dis), n = as.integer(n), 
            as.double(toolong), as.integer(trace), out = double(length(dis)), 
            NAOK = TRUE)$out
    else dis <- .C(C_stepacross, dis = as.double(dis), as.integer(n), 
        as.double(toolong), as.integer(trace), NAOK = TRUE)$dis
    attributes(dis) <- oldatt
    attr(dis, "method") <- paste(attr(dis, "method"), 
        path)
    dis
}
```

Comment: The interface to the C function was last changed in vegan 2.5-1 (Apr 2018) when compiled routines had to be registred in R. It seems that you manage to avoid that registration. Have you loaded vegan in regular way? Do you have stray stepacross R function which is not in the vegan NAMESPACE but in your private workspace? As given, your problem is non-reproducible.

Comment: If you intentionally use obsolete vegan from 2019, you have bad intentions.

Comment: I'm simply relying on a computer that is too old and lacking internet connection to run some repeat analyses from 6 years ago. It's an annoying situation, but I'm dealing with it as best as I can. It's not a bad intention, just a frustrating one.

Comment: to answer your question, I use `library(vegan)` and then run `stepacross()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide a reproducible example, but I can reproduce this problem if I **don't** use `vegan::stepacross`, but a different copy of the function. Check your workspace – it probably has a copy of this function. The C function is registred for use in **vegan** functions, but not for functions in other namespaces. This example will reproduce your problem:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
d <- vegdist(dune)
stepacross <- vegan::stepacross
environment(stepacross) <- environment() ## set to working environment
dd <- stepacross(d, "ext") 
## Error in stepacross(d, "ext") : object 'C_stepacross' not found
dd <- vegan::stepacross(d, "ext") ### this will be OK
rm(stepacross) ## removes the local copy
dd <- stepacross(d, "ext") ## this will be OK: vegan copy was untouched
```

If `getAnyewhere` finds first a **vegan** version of `stepacross`, the last line of its output will be

```r
<environment: namespace:vegan>
```

In your example this line was missing suggesting that your copy of `stepacross` was not in `namespace:vegan`. Moreover, `getAnywhere` should give `package:vegan` as the *first* place where this function was found.

Comment: I tried to produce a reproducible example, but I could not -- I didn't fully understand what was causing the problem. I'm also unclear why this is occurring on my computer as you describe since It's worked fine on this particular computer for weeks leading up to having this issue. Now that you've given me a bit more knowledge of how some of this works on the backend, I'll take a  look again at my problem and see if I can determine the ultimate source of the issue. Thanks!